# Removing multiple elements from an array using IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove multiple items from an array based on their gameID. At the moment my code will only remove a single item.

There is a similar question which had a comment in an answer saying I could use the following but I'm unsure how to add multiple IDs into it:

```
data.filter(e => !ids.includes(e.gameId))
```

This is my code which works on one item (1138) at the moment:

```
var data = $.grep(data, function(e){
return e.gameId != 1138;
});
```

Any help on how to add multiple IDs to this would be gratefully received!

Comment: `[1138].includes(e.gameId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the fact that `Array.indexOf(e)` returns `-1` for elements not present in `Array`:

```
var new_data = $.grep(data, function(e){
    return [1, 2, 3, 1138].indexOf(e.gameId) == -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an an array of all possible IDs you can do this:

```js
let gameID = 1138;
let gameIDArrays = [1138, 1139, etc...];

let newArray = data.filter(e => !gameIDArrays.includes(e.gameId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Function that takes data array and array of ids to filter on. For each element object in data, if `gameId` is included in the ids array, then filter it from the results.

```js
const filterByIds = (data = [], ids = []) => data.filter(
  ({gameId}) => !ids.includes(gameId)
);

const data = [
  { gameId: 123 },
  { gameId: 456 },
  { gameId: 789 },
];

console.log(filterByIds(data, [123]));
console.log(filterByIds(data, [123, 789]));
console.log(filterByIds(data, [789, 123]));
console.log(filterByIds(data, [456, 789, 123]));
```